# monotony of quotient of two function

Tags: calculus, functions

I've been dealing with the ratio $h=\frac{f*g}{f}$ where I know $f$ and $g$ are non-increasing with positive domain and range. Under what condition $h$ is monotonic? I'm trying to narrow down the obvious $h^\prime$ sign to something more useful using the properties of $f$ and $g$. (the $*$ indicates convolution)

I'll appreciate any hints or references that might give me some insight. I'm not a math student, I'm studying electrical engineering.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your functions are differentiable and I am remembering properties of convolution correctly. The fact that $f$ and $g$ have a positive range implies that the convolution is positive. $f$ and $g$ non-increasing implies that $f'\leq 0$ and $g'\leq 0.$ Differentiating $h$ using the quotient rule yields $$h'=\frac{(f)d(f*g)-(f*g)d(f)}{f^2}$$
The denominator is always positive. The derivative of the convolution is also positive. The numerator is of the form $(+)(+)-(+)(-)\geq 0$ where any of the plus/minus could be zero. Thus $h$ is monotonically increasing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But why is derivative of the convolution positive? We know $d(f*g)=df*g=f*dg$ where both $df$ and $dg$ are negative.